# Customize visual manager MFC & BCG library

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, bcg

I am working on our custom visual manager. As I know it is possible, if we derive our own visual manager from existing one. But the problem is to find to correct method which can allow me do the things below...

Let me know please which methods are correct in our case.

So what I override if I want to have:

- Black background of our application(with ribbon) which method is correct? 
  ?
- Tabs with gray background(1)and green top border(2) and white text (3)
  (1)OnFillTab  ?  (2)GetTabFrameColors?   (3)?
- Header dialog with (1)gray background and (2)green top border and (3)white text
  (1) OnFillHeaderCtrlBackground?   (2) ?    (3) ?
- Ribbon with grey background
              ?
- Green background of menu on pressed item
  OnHighlightMenuItem ?
- Green separator between menu item and ribbon
  OnDrawRibbonQATSeparator ?

Comment: This question is much to broad. You have the source code of all routines that paint and draw. So just check it out and debug. Loading the Riboon cpp modules I can't see so much access to the visual manager... ;)

Comment: You have to try and fix repeatedly. It is how I did it. My boss asked me to to do a skin imitating the Windows High Contrast theme for my application and I succeeded, using the approach you described: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673801/how-to-skin-mfc-main-menu?rq=1#comment62753981_11673801